# How to set pagiantion links in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pagination

**View**

```
$aHotelRooms = DB::table('abserve_hotels')->paginate(3);

@foreach($aHotelRooms as $aHotelRoom)
@endforeach
<div class="pagination">
<?php
echo $aHotelRooms->appends('aHotelRooms')->render(); 
?>
```

Here pagination shows the lists according to what I gave in `paginate()`..

But when I click the links in that pagination..It seems to be an `Object not found` `404 error`..

What should I do for this..

Regards Suganya,

Comment: What URLs does `render()` generate? Can you show an example?

Comment: While hovering it shows `http://localhost/Sugan/travelz/public/hotel/hotelresults?page=2` but when I click it it leads to `http://localhost/hotel/hotelresults?page=2` this URL..

Comment: But actually it should leads to my `http://localhost/Sugan/travelz/public/hotel/hotelresults?page=2` link..Am I right!!..

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong Laravel settings. You should point your web server (for example, Apache) to the `public` directory which is inside you Laravel project's root directory. That's why your links are broken.

For example, if your `Sugan` directory is in `c:\MySites\`, you must set up `c:\MySites\Sugan\travelz\public` directory as root directory.

**Update**

To chage root directory in XAMPP:

- Go to C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf
- Open httpd.conf
- Find tag
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
- Edit tag to DocumentRoot
  "C:/xampp/htdocs/myproject/web"
- Now find tag < Directory > and change
  it to < Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/myproject/web" >
- Restart Your Apache

Comment: How should I rectify it..Can you please clarify it!!..Because I'm new to laravel :(

Comment: What web server and OS you use (Apache/Nginx, or maybe software like XAMMP, MAMP, WAMP)?

Comment: Please look at `update` section in my post for instructions.

Comment: @Suganya Rajsekar, if my answer was helpful, please upvote it and choose as best asnwer.

Answer (score 1):

When using `xampp` you can proceed like the following:

```
{!! $aHotelRooms->path('')->appends('aHotelRooms')->render() !!}
```

If `path('')` doesn't work, you can also try `path('/')`.

I always had to use this hack in `xampp`.

Comment: If OP will not change root directory as installation manual says, he'll catch a lot fo other URL related errors, so it's not an option.

Comment: This is the only url related error I had using `xampp` with multiple laravel installations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$aHotelRooms = DB::table('abserve_hotels')->simplePaginate(15);

<div class="container">
    @foreach ($aHotelRooms as $rooms)
         {{ $rooms->name //define here what you need }}
    @endforeach
</div>

{!! $aHotelRooms->links() !!}
```

I am new to laravel. Hope this helps you...!!

Comment: `links()` is for Laravel 4.

Comment: you can also use render().

Comment: You are correct sir, it changed back from `render` to `links` in 5.2. My mistake.